# GtkSourceGutter - How to render icon or text on a specific line

Tags: c, windows, gtk, gtksourceview, gutter

I have inserted custom gtk source gutter renderer pixbuf and I want to render icon on a specific line.

The reference API states that the interface is very similar to that on GtkTreeView, but doesn't work with a tree model.
So... how am I supposed to render data to a specific line if the GtkSourceGutter doesn't work with a tree model?

I checked every function in the entire library, every suggested api and child objects and nothing even hints about that.

It just doesn't make sense. The man page says that the GtkSourceGutterRendererPixbuf is used to display icon IN A CELL.
Doing  `gtk_source_gutter_renderer_pixbuf_set_pixbuf(renderer, pixbuf);` will render the icon for all cells in the gutter.
And if the only way is to draw the pixbuf manually using cairo..what's the point in those renderers ?

How do I render pixbuf **in a specific line** using the gtksourcegutterrenderer?

---

[image]

Comment: Why is nobody answering? There  are even no comments about why nobody is answering. Are those stuff really such a top-secret

Comment: Because gtk section of SO is not very well-populated.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev That's sad. QT is pretty much well-populated comparing to gtk section. And for GUI development in C, what's the alternative.. I believe GTK+ is probably the best for its kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally cannot simply agree with the allegation that creating custom objects is easy. It isn't easy, not to everyone.

Mainly, because, this question is tagged `c` and people who don't know Object-Oriented programming might be unfamiliar with its concepts.

It is a matter of reading and practice.

So do not panic if you don't know how to, for instance create your own widget.

The easiest solution I can think of, doesn't involve creating your own renderer, but rather tell the renderer how to query rendering data.

Just connect the [query-data](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/GtkSourceGutterRenderer.html#GtkSourceGutterRenderer-query-data) signal on your GtkSourceGutterRenderer to a signal handler that looks like this:

```
G_MODULE_EXPORT void gutter_renderer_query_data (GtkSourceGutterRenderer *renderer, GtkTextIter *start, GtkTextIter *end, GtkSourceGutterRendererState state)
{
    GtkSourceView*      view    = NULL;
    GtkSourceBuffer*    buffer  = NULL;
    GSList*             marks   = NULL;
    GdkPixbuf*          pixbuf  = NULL;

    view    = GTK_SOURCE_VIEW(gtk_source_gutter_renderer_get_view(renderer));
    buffer  = GTK_SOURCE_BUFFER(gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view)));

    marks   = gtk_source_buffer_get_source_marks_at_iter(buffer, start, NULL);

    if(marks != NULL)
    {
        char *category = gtk_source_mark_get_category(marks->data);

        if(!g_strcmp0(category, "CERTAIN_CATEGORY")) /* See note 1) */
            pixbuf = gtk_image_get_pixbuf(gtk_image_new_from_file("icon_file_here")); /* See note 2) */

        g_slist_free(marks);
    }

    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(renderer), "pixbuf", pixbuf, "yalign", 0.5, NULL);
}
```

---

**Notes**:

1. GtkSourceMark shares the GtkSourceGutterRenderer interface so you might want to filter your other source marks, by specifying the category of a source mark that is applied to the certain line. Otherwise your custom renderer pixbuf will also be rendered left to your other source marks.
2. You should specify the exact pixbuf you want to render internally. Doing this, you won't have to call `gtk_source_gutter_renderer_pixbuf_set_pixbuf()` . You let the API do the resource handling.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with GtkSourceView, but I can give you some clues.

---

### How it's done by GtkSourceView's author

First of all, we need some links:

- [GtkSourceGutterRendererMarks source code](https://github.com/GNOME/gtksourceview/blob/master/gtksourceview/gtksourcegutterrenderermarks.c)
- [GtkSourceGutterRendererPixbuf source code](https://github.com/GNOME/gtksourceview/blob/master/gtksourceview/gtksourcegutterrendererpixbuf.c)
- [GtkSourceGutterRenderer documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/GtkSourceGutterRenderer.html)

Let's start with GtkSourceGutterRendererPixbuf. From it's `class_init` method we find out, that it overrides only `draw` method. It's only purpose is to render a pixbuf or icon. Pure drawing.

However, GtkSourceGutterRenderer documentation says, that there is a `query-data` signal which can be used to tune Renderer's internal state. At this point we should take a look at GtkSourceGutterRendererMarks which is inherited from RendererPixbuf. It doesn't override `draw`, but overrides `query_data`. *(For some reason `GtkSourceGutterRendererClass` is not described in the documentation. I don't know why.)*

```
/* Read my comments. */
static void
gutter_renderer_query_data (GtkSourceGutterRenderer      *renderer,
                            GtkTextIter                  *start,
                            GtkTextIter                  *end,
                            GtkSourceGutterRendererState  state)
{
  GSList *marks;
  GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = NULL;
  
  view = GTK_SOURCE_VIEW (gtk_source_gutter_renderer_get_view (renderer));
  buffer = GTK_SOURCE_BUFFER (gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (view)));

  marks = gtk_source_buffer_get_source_marks_at_iter (buffer,
                                                      start,
                                                      NULL);
  
  /* If there are marks, we find a pixbuf for one of them. 
   * Otherwise pixbuf is NULL. */
  if (marks != NULL)
  {
    size = measure_line_height (view);
    pixbuf = composite_marks (view, marks, size);

    g_slist_free (marks);
  }
  
  /* Now tell parent class to render certain pixbuf
   * It will render nothing if pixbuf is NULL. */
  g_object_set (G_OBJECT (renderer),
                   "pixbuf", pixbuf,
                   NULL);
}
```

---

### My recommendations.

You want to draw marks at certain lines (e.g. want to highlight current debugger line). If I were you, I would have inherited from RendererPixbuf, overriden `query_data` and use `gtk_text_iter_get_line` on `GtkTextIter *start`. Looks like that's the bare minimum.

Feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: I could do pure drawing on the text view, but that would be plenty of work (handle vscroll, keeping track of all "mark" locations and redrawing them respectively, etc..) I've done this before, but this time, before repeating the same obfuscation (that is not in GTK+ taste) I decided to ask, because this seemed like something that must have support. Unfortunately I don't have enough practice with overriding/inheriting. I have implemented exactly two widgets so far, the rest is plain GTK+, functions and hacks.

Comment: Subclassing from GObject is not a difficult thing. Official howto can be found [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject.html).

Comment: To make things easier you can take `gtksourcegutterrenderermarks` header and source and tune them. In .h you change `GTK_SOURCE` , `GtkSource` and `gtk_source` to your prefix (for example, `MLN`, `Mln` and `mln` responsibly); `GUTTER_RENDERER_MARKS`, `GutterRendererMarks` and`gutter_renderer_marks` to your class name (say, `GUTTER_RENDERER_DEBUGGER`, `GutterRendererDebugger` and `gutter_renderer_debugger`). Don't touch lines containing `parent`. Then make corresponding changes in .c file.

Comment: If gtksourcemarks use gtksourcegutterrenderermarks then I cannot just change the source file. As you can see in the screenshot, I am also using source marks

Comment: You should make a copy and then change it.

Comment: To which "my class" you are referring to? Sorry I've done a lot to this point, now I want it to be clear what I should do that will work.

Comment: My recommendation was to write your own renderer. It should be a subclass of GtkSourceGutterRendererPixbuf. To make your own class you can make a copy of renderermarks code (both .h and .c) and modify them.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't want to write all that from scratch myself. I knew I could do that, but even if I wanted I am not sure I could. Especially if I am uncertain. Even if I write my own GutterRenderer that inherits from GtkSourceGutterRendererPixbuf how do I make it do the job? i.e a function to draw the pixbuf based on text iter. You are suggesting me to copy gtksourcemark source code? This is not really helping. If there is no way to do this and I have to invent the way, this is not what I was expecting. Maybe you can at least tell me the steps of how to do it?

Comment: And I don't just mean "a brief overview of what could be done" I mean real steps, perhaps with examples or pseudo-code of what really needs to be done. I knew it won't be easy, but this looks even harder than just drawing on top of textview. (the gutter part).

Comment: I am not going to write code. I've already told you the steps: make a subclass of GtkSourceGutterRendererPixbuf, override `query_data` method. In your `query_data` get line number from `textiter` and if that you want to draw something on that line - set "pixbuf" property.

Comment: `query_data` will be called for each line. It's not called once. If you have 200 lines visible, it will be called 200 times. The list of lines can be stored in private section (see `G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_PRIVATE`)

Comment: That was very unclear, not to mention that what you have suggested doesn't work in many, many aspects.